# Wildcard Cer is not working after configured ssl host headers

Tags: ssl, iis-6

I have a regular cer installed on my main domain http://www.2send.co.il , and a wildcard SSL installed on the sub-domain http://en.2send.co.il .

I am using 'SSL host headers' to use one IP address for both sites. the problem is that when I am checking the SSL (http://sslchecker.com/sslchecker) for the sub-domain the response is that the hostname is not match. for the main domain it works properly.

I don't know where to start looking for the solution.

Any idea?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use the same certificate (wildcard certificate) to all the sub-domains.
First install the certificate on one of the sub-domains, then configure the SSL host headers as described here: http://www.sslshopper.com/article-how-to-configure-ssl-host-headers-in-iis-6.html , this will use the certificate from the first sub-domain to the second one.